# Programmatically Building Metadata Navigation

Tags: 2013, navigation, managed-metadata

I'm trying to build metadata navigation programmatically so it can be deployed in a feature event receiver and have been using the code from [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.publishing.navigation.navigationtermset.aspx), but am unable to get a simple link to work.

The code I'm running is unmodified from the example, except that the `SPSite` and `SPWeb` objects are coming from the feature event receiver properties, but whenever I get to this line

```
NavigationTerm term1 = navTermSet.CreateTerm("Term 1", NavigationLinkType.SimpleLink);
```

I get an `ArgumentException`  with the message `"The URL does not point to a page".` Which is interesting because I haven't specified a URL for the link yet!

Has anyone got this working successfully in 2013 and can see where I've gone wrong?

**EDIT** - Full code

```
public override void FeatureActivated(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties)
{
    var site = (SPSite)properties.Feature.Parent;
    var web = site.RootWeb;

    var webNavSettings = new WebNavigationSettings(web);

    // Set basic nav settings
    webNavSettings.CurrentNavigation.Source = StandardNavigationSource.TaxonomyProvider;
    webNavSettings.AddNewPagesToNavigation = false;
    webNavSettings.CreateFriendlyUrlsForNewPages = false;

    // Set navigation term set
    TaxonomySession taxonomySession = new TaxonomySession(site, true);

    if (taxonomySession.TermStores.Count > 0)
    {
        TermStore termStore = taxonomySession.TermStores[0];
        TermSet existingTermSet = termStore.GetTermSet(NavTermSetId);

        if (existingTermSet != null)
        {
            existingTermSet.Delete();
            termStore.CommitAll();
        }

        Group siteCollectionGroup = termStore.GetSiteCollectionGroup(site);
        TermSet termSet = siteCollectionGroup.CreateTermSet("Navigation", NavTermSetId);

        NavigationTermSet navTermSet = NavigationTermSet.GetAsResolvedByWeb(
            termSet, web, StandardNavigationProviderNames.GlobalNavigationTaxonomyProvider);
        navTermSet.IsNavigationTermSet = true;
        navTermSet.TargetUrlForChildTerms.Value = "~site/default.aspx";
        termStore.CommitAll();

        NavigationTerm term1 = navTermSet.CreateTerm("Home", NavigationLinkType.SimpleLink);
        term1.SimpleLinkUrl = "~site/default.aspx";

        termStore.CommitAll();
    }
    webNavSettings.Update();
}
```

Comment: Is it the same if you use FriendlyUrl like var newNavTerm = navTermSetItem.CreateTerm(term.Name, NavigationLinkType.FriendlyUrl);

Comment: This is really strange, you use the exact same code that I do (successfully) except you are creating a SimpleLink instead of a FriendlyUrl. But that is not even where your code is throwing errors. and the /default.aspx URL is valid I guess?

Comment: Assuming ~site is expanding correctly, yes. I've tried it with a full URL, but it does't like that either.

Answer (score 2):

Have you set `TargetUrlForChildTerms`?

I have the following code working:

```
TermSet newTermSet = siteCollectionGroup.CreateTermSet("Term set", NavTermSetId);
NavigationTermSet navTermSet = NavigationTermSet.GetAsResolvedByWeb(newTermSet, parentWeb,
                        StandardNavigationProviderNames.CurrentNavigationTaxonomyProvider);
navTermSet.IsNavigationTermSet = true;
navTermSet.TargetUrlForChildTerms.Value = "~site/Pages/default.aspx";
ts.CommitAll();
```

and then adding nodes:

```
.... // for eaching over the structure I create pages and nav terms for
navTermSet.CreateTerm(term.Name, NavigationLinkType.FriendlyUrl);
....
ts.CommitAll();
```

Comment: What is the type of `ts`?

Comment: Sorry, that is my TermStore.

Comment: OK, I've added `navTermSet.TargetUrlForChildTerms.Value = "~site/default.aspx";` (~site/Pages/default.aspx does not exist) but am now getting the same ArgumentException from that line instead.

Comment: Weird, can you post your full code so we can take a closer look?

Comment: Posted in original question.